# Python a* search for coloring maze problem

Tags: python, search, artificial-intelligence, a-star

I try to create a a* search for maze coloring game. I had my example mazes to do the search but the issue is it did not work properly. X's are walls. 0's path and S is for start. the goal is go over all cells and paint them(turn them to 1). But when we choose direction it should move until it hits something
(example of the game for better understanding: https://www.mathplayground.com/logic_color_maze )

The Successor is where I stuck for now. I try to implement run the successor for one step and try to see the results mazes of child nodes but it did not change the mazes properly. In maze1 S stuck on X and for the others I cannot see any child node.

I try to create a a* search for maze coloring game. I had my example mazes to do the search but the issue is it did not work properly. X's are walls. 0's path and S is for start. the goal is go over all cells and paint them(turn them to 1). But when we choose direction it should move until it hits something
(example of the game for better understanding: https://www.mathplayground.com/logic_color_maze )

```
maze1 = [
    ['S', '0', '0', 'X', '0', '0'],
    ['X', 'X', '0', 'X', '0', '0'],
    ['0', '0', '0', 'X', '0', 'X'],
    ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'],
    ['0', 'X', 'X', 'X', '0', '0'],
    ['0', '0', '0', 'X', '0', '0']
]
maze2 = [
    ['0', '0', '0', 'X', '0', '0'],
    ['X', 'X', '0', 'X', '0', '0'],
    ['0', '0', '0', 'X', '0', 'X'],
    ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'],
    ['0', 'X', 'X', 'X', '0', '0'],
    ['S', '0', '0', 'X', '0', '0']
]
maze3 = [
    ['0', '0', '0', 'X', '0', '0'],
    ['X', 'X', '0', 'X', '0', '0'],
    ['0', '0', '0', 'X', '0', 'X'],
    ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'],
    ['0', 'X', 'X', 'X', '0', '0'],
    ['0', '0', 'S', 'X', '0', '0']
]
maze4 = [
    ['0', '0', 'S', 'X', '0', '0'],
    ['X', 'X', '0', 'X', '0', '0'],
    ['0', '0', '0', 'X', '0', 'X'],
    ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'],
    ['0', 'X', 'X', 'X', '0', '0'],
    ['0', '0', '0', 'X', '0', '0']
]
maze5 = [
    ['S', '0', '0', 'X', '0', '0'],
    ['0', 'X', '0', 'X', '0', '0'],
    ['0', '0', '0', 'X', '0', 'X'],
    ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'],
    ['0', 'X', 'X', 'X', '0', '0'],
    ['0', '0', '0', 'X', '0', '0']
]
```

I created a mazeNode class:

```
class mazeNode:
    def __init__(self, maze, parent, cost) -> None:
        self.maze = maze
        self.parent = parent
        self.cost = cost
```

Try to identify possible directions that we can go in maze

```
def get_possible_moves(position, maze):
    directions = [(-1, 0), (1, 0), (0, -1), (0, 1)]
    possible_moves = []

    for direction in directions:
        x, y = position
        x += direction[0]
        y += direction[1]

        if (x >= 0 and x < len(maze) and y >= 0 and y < len(maze[0]) and maze[x][y] != 'X'):
            possible_moves.append((x, y))

    return possible_moves
```

The goal state which is making all possible cells 1 in maze:

```
def goal(n):
    for row in n.maze:
        for i in row:
            if i != 0:
                continue
            else:
                return False
            
    return True
```

Finding the location of S:

```
def findCord(mazeNode):
    for row_idx, row in enumerate(mazeNode.maze):
        for col_idx, i in enumerate(row):
            if i == "S":
                s_position = (row_idx, col_idx)
                return s_position
```

the Cost function which is max value of the difference from start position to end position:

```
def cost(nodeParent, nodeChild):
    xParent, yParent = findCord(nodeParent)
    xChild, yChild = findCord(nodeChild)
    
    xdif = abs(xParent - xChild)
    ydif = abs(yParent - yChild)
    
    return xdif + ydif
```

and the successor function:

```
def successor2(myMazeNode):
    s_position = findCord(myMazeNode)
    possible_moves = get_possible_moves(s_position, myMazeNode.maze)
    
    child_mazeNodes = []
    for move in possible_moves:
        x, y = s_position
        new_maze = copy.deepcopy(myMazeNode.maze)
        x += move[0]
        y += move[1]
        while (x >= 0 and x < len(new_maze) and y >= 0 and y < len(new_maze[0]) and new_maze[x][y] != 'X'):
            if new_maze[x][y] == '0':
                new_maze[x][y] = '1'
            x += move[0]
            y += move[1]

        # Move back to the last valid position
        x -= move[0]
        y -= move[1]

        # Place S in the new position and mark the previous position as visited
        new_maze[s_position[0]][s_position[1]] = '1'
        new_maze[x][y] = 'S'

        child_mazeNode = mazeNode(new_maze, myMazeNode, myMazeNode.cost)
        child_mazeNode.cost += cost(child_mazeNode, myMazeNode)
        
        mazes = [x.maze for x in child_mazeNodes]
        
        if child_mazeNode not in mazes:
            child_mazeNodes.append(child_mazeNode)

    return child_mazeNodes
```

the Successor is where I stuck for now. I try to implement run the successor for one step and try to see the results mazes of child nodes but it did not change the mazes properly. In maze1 S stuck on X and for the others I cannot see any child node. The main issue is it works proper in maze1 and maze5 while the start is (0, 0) but for the others it did not work and create child nodes.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example